# Array allocation in julia closure

Tags: arrays, closures, julia, allocation, lexical-scope

I wonder is it a good idea to allocate temporary arrays in let-block, which wraps some function?
Some toy example: instead of

```
function foo(x)
    y = zeros(100)
    for i in 1 : 100
        y[i] = 2*x[i] - 1
    end
    do_something(y)
end
```

I will write something like:

```
let
  const y = zeros(100) # otherwise foo will be type-unstable due to 'global' y
  function foo(x)
    for i in 1 : 100
        y[i] = 2*x[i] - 1
    end
    do_something(y)
  end
end
```

It can be easily checked via @benchmark macro that in the second case memory for y-array will be allocated only once, which significantly improves performance (in my not-toy case). I'm wondering is it a "julian-way" to do such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you an answer for Julia 1.0. For earlier versions of Julia the situation would be a bit different.

Point 1. Your code with `let` will not run under Julia 1.0 as `let` creates local scope and in local scope you are not allowed to use `const`.

Point 2. It is fully OK to do something like this in global scope:

```
const y = zeros(100) # otherwise foo will be type-unstable due to 'global' y
function foo(x)
    for i in 1 : 100
        y[i] = 2*x[i] - 1
    end
    do_something(y)
end
```

and you will have good performance as Julia 1.0 knows that `y` has constant type and will optimize it. The consequence is that you will have `y` in global scope and `foo` in methods table (i.e. you can call `foo` using its name).

Point 3. You can also use `let` block like this:

```
const foo = let y = zeros(100)
    function inner_foo(x)
        for i in 1 : 100
            y[i] = 2*x[i] - 1
        end
        do_something(y)
    end
end
```

This time `y` is defined only in local scope and does not leak out to global scope. Also `inner_foo` is not defined in global scope therefore you have to assign the return value of let block to a variable `foo` that then can be used to make calls (I make it a `const` to improve performance if it gets used in some functions later on)

Point 4. Note, however, that this almost identical code will not be as good, as Julia 1.0 has problems with type inference of variable `y` (hopefully this will be fixed in the future)

```
const foo = let
    y = zeros(100)
    function inner_foo(x)
        for i in 1 : 100
            y[i] = 2*x[i] - 1
        end
        do_something(y)
    end
end
```

In summary: the decision if you use `let` block depends mostly on what you have to be visible in `global` scope (as what is defined in `let` is not visible in global scope) and if you use `let` block it is best to define variables you want to use as a part of `let` block definition.